# how to scale out kubeflow pipelines (using vertex ai), or it just done automatically

Tags: google-ai-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I'm running a kubeflow pipleine with different components for stages like data preprocessing, training etc.

i've understand that i can use specific image for each stage (component).
(for example image that not or using a gpu for training.

my question is how the pipleline can set to scale out for different stages (components)?

or it just done automatically

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of resources allocated on each component (step), due to [containerization](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/introduction#understanding_ml_pipelines), are capped by the resources on which it is running.
For GCP products (e.g. Dataflow, AutoML) that are used in the pipeline, the resources are automatically scaled based on that [product scalability](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/scalable-and-resilient-apps).
It is possible to create custom components, and for this Vertex AI allows for you to choose the amount of resources (e.g. machine type, CPU limit, GPU limit) for [each step](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline#specify-machine-type). For custom training there are [more options available](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/configure-compute#specifying_gpu) that you can also select in order to create more efficient flows.